# htaccess code remove www and id and php in sub directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

with this code and clean URL like (example.com) I could add www and remove id in url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.*/)?(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But now my root of website is in a folder.

so my new url is www.examole.com/newfolder

how can add newfolder to top code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this .htaccess in `/newfolder`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newfolder/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.*/)?(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```